# Specific array elements combinations

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combinations

I have a two dimensional array of strings values:

> ABC
>   
>  -D-
>   
>  -FG

where "-" means empty value. 
What I want to achieve is to get all combinations of array elements "from left to right", so the results of given array should be:

> ABC 
>   
>  ADC 
>   
>  AFC 
>   
>  AFG 
>   
>  ABG 
>   
>  ADG

Empty values should be ommitted and order of items should be kept.
The problem is the number of array columns and rows is not fixed.
I tried to play with loop in loop (and loop) and recursion but with no success. Also cartesian product is usless in this case as it will produce needless combinations (I tried to create sql temporary tables dynamically and store the values in them making cross join).
Coud someone to show me a way, please?

Comment: Where is `ABCG` etc.? It looks like the G is in a 4th position. (I replaced your screenshot with text, but refer to it https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNClv.png and please correct me if I'm wrong...)

Comment: ABCG is not required. We only build as many charakter as array columns count. From left to right. If array had 4 columns 4th character would be required.

Comment: But there are 4 columns in the 3rd row. How would the combinations differ if the 3rd row were "-FG"?

Comment: You are correct, there should be 3 columns in each row. Third row should be -FG.That's my mistake, sorry.

Comment: Ok, edited for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you can do this by using an array to hold, for each column, the index of the row containing the value to be output. Initially this array will hold the first non-empty row for each column. At each iteration you increment, starting at the lowest column, the row to be indexed, until you get a non-empty value or you reach the end of the rows, in which case you set the row back to the first non-empty value and move on to the next column. This resembles the action of an old odometer in a car.

Here's some Java code to illustrate (sorry, I'm not familiar with VB.Net)

```
    char[][] values = {
            {'A', 'B', 'C'}, 
            {'-', 'D', '-'}, 
            {'-', 'F', 'G'}
            };

    int rows = values.length;
    int cols = values[0].length;

    int[] idx = new int[cols];

    // for each column, find the first non-empty character
    int i=0;
    for(; i<cols; i++)
    {
        while(idx[i] < rows && values[idx[i]][i] == '-') idx[i]++;
        if(idx[i] == rows) break;
    }

    // if a column was missing a non-empty value then we can't proceed
    if(i<cols) 
    {
        System.out.println("Missing value in column " + i);
        return;
    }

    while(true)
    {
        // print current solution
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) 
            System.out.print(values[idx[j]][j]);
        System.out.println();

        int k=0;
        for(; k<cols; k++)
        {
            // find next non-empty character
            do idx[k]++; while(idx[k] < rows && values[idx[k]][k] == '-');

            // if there was one, break
            if(idx[k] < rows) break;

            // else, wrap around to 0, but then find next non-empty row
            idx[k] = 0;
            while(values[idx[k]][k] == '-') idx[k]++;
        }

        // if the last index wrapped around then we're done
        if(k == cols) break;
    }
```

Output:

```
ABC
ADC
AFC
ABG
ADG
AFG
```

Comment: Possible enhancement for large data set: squeeze columns before main treatment to make `{{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'-', 'D', 'G'}, {'-', 'F', '-'}};` with column counts `{1,3,2}` to avoid instant checking inside main loop.